# MySQL table(s) for tracking mixed group of users (logged in and guests)

Tags: mysql, database

I'm having trouble with database design, for tracking visitor activity for a mixed group of users.

Some of the users are logged in on WordPress, and thus have IDs.  Others are guests, so I want to assign them a unique ID that won't clash with the WordPress ID, and store that as a cookie.

Database normalization, as I understand it, calls for an activity table, and a separate user table.  But the logged in users already have a user table in WordPress, and I don't want to clutter that table up with guest entries, since the table has a lot of fields, and all I really need to know about the guest is that the ID is unique.

Should I just create an additional two-column user table, with tracking ID the primary key, and a field for wordpress_id that is empty for cookie-guests?

Or do I even need a table for the guest IDs - is it enough their IDs are unique? Just assign guests a negative ID number so they never clash with the WordPress ID?

Having a difficult time with this design, guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: a) there are a lot of wp plugins that do what you want to do b) Your tracking ids should be independent from your wordpress ids! I would use a table with your tracking id and, as soon as revealed, add the wordpress id there (if you actually insert all tracking ids here is personal preference, I'd like to do it). And an advice: use a random tracking id each time (e.g. by a hashfunction), otherwise you reveal the usercount. So I'd suggest (id, cookiecode, wordpress_id). And check what happens if user forbids cookies, you might end up adding an id for every page, so use a sessionvariable with id.

Comment: Your answer reinforces what I suspected - a separate table needed for tracking IDs.  Re: cookies, my idea was if not logged in and no cookie returned, set a cookie identifying just the resource visited - record no database entry.  Then if they give that cookie back on the next pull, they are accepting cookies, so assign them a guest ID and record *both* hits.  I'm less concerned about the aggregate hit count including guests than individual counts for resources updated since the user's last visit to that resource.  That make sense?